# AJAX responses adding additional line break

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I have a dropdown that looks like this:

```
<select class="quick-drop" id="block-type-drop">
  <option value="Block">Block</option>
  <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
</select>
```

I make an ajax request that gets one of these values from the database. The value is stored in a variable called `data`.

```
function changeSelectedBlockType(property, subProperty, position) {
    //check if position is display only
    jQuery.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {
            'action': 'getBlockType', 
            'property': property, 
            'subProperty': subProperty,
            'position': position
        }
    })
    .done(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        //jQuery('#block-type-drop option[value="' + data +'"]').prop('selected', true);
        jQuery('#block-type-drop').val(data).change();
        //jQuery('#block-type-drop').change();
    })
    .fail(function(data) {
        console.log('Failed AJAX Call! /// Return Data: ' + data);
    });
}
```

I then attempt to change the selected option like this:

```
jQuery('#block-type-drop').val(data).change();
```

The selected option becomes blank. I tested the value by writing it to the console to see if there was an extra space or incorrect value but it looks good.

Also I attempted to change the selected option by using:

```
jQuery('#block-type-drop option[value="' + data +'"]').prop('selected', true);
```

This would do nothing rather than make the selected option blank.
Using `console.log(jQuery().jquery);` reports that my jQuery version is 1.12.4 if that helps. I'm not sure what version was running previously but I suspect that it was recently updated.

Any ideas? I'm at a loss.

EDIT:
The code itself is correct. When writing the data variable to console I noticed that the variable had an extra line break before it. After further investigation this seems to be happening to all variables returned from AJAX calls. No clue why this is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Not need for complicated code. The answer is actually really simple:

```
jQuery('#block-type-drop').val(data);
```

That's it. You change the value of the select to your `data` String and the select updates its selection accordingly.

But it is important that `data` represents a value 1:1. Same captitalization etc.

See simple example here:

```js
$(function(){

$('#clickme').on('click', function(){
$('#block-type-drop').val('Weekly');
});

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="quick-drop" id="block-type-drop">
  <option value="Block">Block</option>
  <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
</select>

<button id="clickme">Change selection</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

There can only be a problem with data, check it again.. as you can see here working and non working example.. Check also uppercase & lowercase letters..

```js
function callonclick(valueset) {
  jQuery('#block-type-drop').val(valueset).trigger('change');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="quick-drop" id="block-type-drop">
  <option value="Block">Block</option>
  <option value="Monthly">Monthly</option>
  <option value="Weekly">Weekly</option>
</select>

<button onclick="callonclick('Monthly');">Set value `Monthly`</button>
<button onclick="callonclick('monthly');">Set value `monthly` results in blank</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was being created by an extra line at the end of the closing `?>` tag in one of my php files.